# How can I input more than one word into a custom String using operator>>?

Tags: c++, string, class, directory

I am a first year student, and I was given the C++ language to use to build a dictionary.

I have a problem that I can't put in more than one word at a time into a custom `String` class that I am writing.

For example, I want to input `"Hello world"`, but my output is just `"Hello"`:

```
class String{
private:
    int size;
    char* string;
};

istream& operator >> (istream& input, String& str){
    cout << "Enter Size" << endl;
    input >> str.size;
    str.string = new char[str.size];
    cout << "Enter Name" << endl;
    input >> str.string; // WHAT I NEED TO DO HERE??
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Your `String` class is lacking a great number of functions. For such a class, look at the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If that looks discouraging, consider using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::istream` [`operator>>` for `char*` input](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) (and [for `std::string` input](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)) reads *whitespace-delimited* words.  Leading whitespace is ignored, and then reading stops when new whitespace is encountered.  Whitespace includes space, tab, and line break characters, for instance.

Since your custom `operator>>` is prompting the user to supply the exact string length (why?), you should use the [`istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) method to read exactly that many characters, instead of using `istream`'s `operator>>`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class String{
private:
    int size;
    char* string;

public:
    ...

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, String& str);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& input, String& str)
{
    cout << "Enter Size" << endl;
    int size = 0;
    if (input >> size)
    {
        char* data = new char[size];
        cout << "Enter Name" << endl;
        input >> ws;
        if (input.read(data, size))
        {
            delete[] str.string;
            str.string = data;
            str.size = size;
        }
        else
            delete[] data;
    }
    return input;
}
```

That being said, your `String` class is missing quite a bit of other required functionalities, which I'm assuming you either haven't implemented yet, or just didn't show here, including constructors, destructors, and assignment operators, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).